# Very tight icon when window is maximized

Tags: windows, qt

I have a Windows application created using QT.

My icon in the top left of the window is extra tight when the window is maximized. Actually, on my screen, the logo is cropped.

Below is a screenshot of the problem. (It shows the top left of the screen when the window is maximised; notice there is no padding between the edge of the screen and the logo.)

[image]

Comment: Thats just the way Windows 7 does it. You should fix the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the behaviour as designed. Here's what my app looks like, for example:

[image]

If you want to add some padding you'll need to add it to your icon.

Comment: Is there a way to override QT without changing the icon?

Comment: Qt has nothing to do with it. It's Windows that paints this.